# Intent on Android

Tags: android

I want a clarification on intent.this is my scenario,there are 3 activities in my project namely **"A","B","C"**.....
On clicking the button in Activity **"A"** ,i pass the values to "B" through bundle and based on the received value i retrieved set of values from database...Similarly **"B"**->**"C"** also...

The problem when i clicked the back button in **"C"** it does not proceed to **"B"** rather throws a error.similarly **"B**" to **"A"** also....

i found the reason that "B" can not get value from bundle when clicking Back button from "C"

Hope you understand.what's the solution....

Thanks in advance

Comment: Apart from some code, it would be really useful to tell us what error is thrown when pressing back.

Comment: it will obvious that null pointer exception will be thrown because when you press back your activity start from "Oncreate" method and it will not get values...So nullpointer will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting our Activity using `startActivityForResult` and use `setResult(int)` to send the result back from Activity **C** to **B**

Comment: You'll also need to check the result code for being equal to RESULT_OK(-1) as it will be RESULT_CANCELED(0) when the back key is hit before you try to retrieve and extras from the Intent. To be doubly safe check that the Intent isn't null. AND you'll need to use setResult(int ResultCode, Intent data) when returning, not just the setResult(int Result Code)

Comment: for 'retrieve and extras', read 'retrieve any extras'. -typo, sorry

Answer (score 0):

that true you saying bundle getting null values, so you have to prevent that null values,
like first check bundle values if not Equals null then only set

```
Intent myintent = getIntent();
if (null != myintent.getExtras()) {
    // do your work here
    String Name = myintent.getExtras().getString("Name");
} else {
    // not here you can't get values
    // so getting force close here
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Recor Here..", 12).show();
}
```